# Predicate in Java11 filters all elements

Tags: java, predicate, java-11, functional-interface

I am moving to use Java11. Learning a new method *Predicate.not*, I found my current code to find only cat family as:

```
List<String> animals = List.of("cat", "leopard", "dog", "lion", "horse");
Predicate<String> cats = a -> !a.equals("dog") && !a.equals("horse");
Set<String> filterCat = animals.stream().filter(cats).collect(Collectors.toSet());
System.out.println(filterCat);
```

output is :

> leopard, cat, lion

Now I am trying to use the new method and the output is coming incorrect. How do I correct it? What did I do wrong?

My later code:

```
Predicate<String> updatedCatFilter = Predicate.not(a -> a.equals("dog") && a.equals("horse"));
Set<String> catFamily = animals.stream().filter(updatedCatFilter).collect(Collectors.toSet());
System.out.println(filterCat);
```

But this outputs all my list now.

> horse, leopard, cat, dog, lion

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> What did I do wrong?

You seem to be missing the basic [De-morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) which states that

```
!(a || b) == !a && !b
```

and

```
!(a && b) == !a || !b
```

---

> How do I correct it?

So you should ***change your code to use***

```
Predicate.not(a -> a.equals("dog") || a.equals("horse")); // !(a || b)
```

which shall be equivalent to your existing code

```
Predicate<String> cats = a -> !a.equals("dog") && !a.equals("horse");
```

that can also be looked upon as:

```
Predicate<String> notDog = a -> !a.equals("dog");
Predicate<String> notHorse =  a -> !a.equals("horse");
Predicate<String> cats = notDog.and(notHorse); // !a && !b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it in that way:

```java
List<String> animals = List.of("cat", "leopard", "dog", "lion", "horse");
Set<String> filterCat = animals.stream()
    .filter(Predicate.not("dog"::equals).and(Predicate.not("horse"::equals)))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
System.out.println(filterCat);
```